# NTOP gives warnings on startup

Tags: networking, monitoring, bandwidth, ntop

I just installed ntop 1.4.4 and when I start it, it give me infinite warnings "packet truncated":

```
...
RRD_DEBUG:     umask 0066
RRD_DEBUG:     DirPerms 0700
THREADMGMT: RRD: Started thread (t2992630672) for data collection
THREADMGMT[t2992630672]: RRD: Data collection thread starting [p30923]
INIT: Created pid file (/var/run/ntop.pid)
THREADMGMT[t3086329552]: ntop RUNSTATE: INITNONROOT(3)
Now running as requested user 'nobody' (99:99)
Note: Reporting device initally set to 0 [eth0] (merged)
THREADMGMT[t3086329552]: ntop RUNSTATE: RUN(4)
THREADMGMT[t2982140816]: NPS(1): Started thread for network packet sniffing [eth0]
THREADMGMT[t2982140816]: NPS(eth0): pcapDispatch thread starting [p30923]
THREADMGMT[t2982140816]: NPS(eth0): pcapDispatch thread running [p30923]
THREADMGMT[t3047009168]: SIH: Idle host scan thread running [p30923]
THREADMGMT[t3057499024]: SFP: Fingerprint scan thread running [p30923]
**WARNING** packet truncated (8814->8232)
**WARNING** packet truncated (10274->8232)
**WARNING** packet truncated (8814->8232)
**WARNING** packet truncated (8814->8232)
...
```

Do I need to configure something?

I tried to access the web interface (http://localhost:3000) but it does not work.

Note: I'm on CentOS.

**EDIT:**

Not sure if it helps but there is my "ifconfig":

```
eth0
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:76:BC:7E:77  
inet addr:192.168.0.221  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::216:76ff:febc:7e77/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:15496640 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:19256813 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:836230629 (797.4 MiB)  TX bytes:608496148 (580.3 MiB)
Memory:dffe0000-e0000000
```

Comment: Can you provide the ifconfig output for eth0?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is what you want, but I will edit my question and add the "ifconfig".

Comment: Is libpcap >= 0.8.?

Comment: @Grizly I seem to have libcap 0.9.4.

Comment: I got nothing, it seems the searches I did only found older versions with that error which were apparently "Fixed in the CVS"..

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving these warnings because it was larger than the MTU of the outgoing network interface. It isn't really a big deal, just filter those error messages if it is a big problem.